# Android Studio countdowntimer seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, countdowntimer

I have made a countdowntimer in android studio. It has a progress bar that shows its progress. However, I want a seekbar to seek to a specific time in the countdown. I'm not sure how to do this. 
I want to be able to drag the seekbar and the countdowntimer to change accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am done with this many time before.. fortunately have source of that...

```
mTxtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
    mSkbCountDown = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.count_down);
    mSkbCountDown.setProgress(mSkbCountDown.getMax());

    new MyCountDown(100000, 1000).start();

 public class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        mSkbCountDown.setMax((int) millisInFuture);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mTxtTime.setText("It Finished...!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
        mTxtTime.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "."+ millisUntilFinished % 1000);
        mSkbCountDown.setProgress((int) (timeRemaining));
        //Log.i(TAG, "Time tick: " + millisUntilFinished);
    }
```

May this helps you.. works fine with me...

Comment: This is good for setting the seekbar progress, but if i drag the seekbar, i want it to set the countdown progress as well.